# Replace both SplitView screens with one ViewController screen

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I can't seem to find this navigation use case for iPad SplitViewController. Using Storyboard, I have created a SplitViewController that shows Master/Detail and it works great. From my detail view, I want to have a button that completely replaces the entire SplitViewController (both master and detail screens) with a single ViewController.

Ideally, this would be a navigation that would allow back button function to return to the SplitViewController but I'm open to other solutions as long as the ViewController is using the full screen (I need every piece of screen real estate possible - and it will have popovers if that is of any consequence to the solution).

I assume this is possible and sure I'm not the first that needs to do this but I've searched quite a bit and found similar use cases, but not exact.

Here's my current layout in Storyboard:

- TabBarView

  - SplitView A

    - Navigation

      - Master

        - Navigation > TableView
      - Detail
  - SplitView B

    - Navigation

      - Master

        - Navigation > TableView
      - Detail
- Full Screen ViewController (where does this go in the above structure?)

So I need SplitView B to Navigate to the Full Screen ViewController that is not yet integrated into this screen navigation tree because I don't know where or how it would be placed in this structure.

Any suggestions on how to setup my Storyboard and/or use custom code to implement? I have tried man different ways to wire this but keep coming up short of what I need.

Comment: <crickets/> No none has any advice? Can't believe I'm the only one with this requirement.

Comment: I suppose you must resolved but I create a Notification in master and call after update detail or when you need it.

Comment: I didn't but I have long since moved off of that project. Thanks for the tip though.